# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that pulls json data and converts it to a readable format.

It is returning the error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line `container.append($.nano(template, events[0]));`

I have tried to find answers on stackoverflow which include:

- ensure jquery is loaded first
- wrap function in a document ready
- include jquery only once

I have done all of the above and have replicated the problem in this jsfiddle

**http://jsfiddle.net/FXcX3/**

Comment: Seems like `$.nano` does not exist. The function `nano` does though... sooo, just drop the `$.` part?

Comment: @FelixKling nano is on line 244 in the fiddle. I'm not sure where I'm not defining it.

Comment: You are defining a **function** `nano` (just as I acknowledged), but the jQuery object `$` doesn't have a **property** `nano`. To learn more about JavaScript functions, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling nano incorrectly, it's not a method of jQuery. It should be like this (from the [documentation](https://github.com/trix/nano)):

```
container.append(nano(nogig));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4pe3j/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
nano is on line 244 in the fiddle. I'm not sure where I'm not defining it.
```

On that line, you have this:

```
function nano(template, data) {
    return template.replace(/\{([\w\.]*)\}/g, function (str, key) {
        var keys = key.split("."),
            v = data[keys.shift()];
        for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) v = v[keys[i]];
        return (typeof v !== "undefined" && v !== null) ? v : "";
    });
}
```

This is defined on the global scope, so change `$.nano` to `nano`.